# Can I reuse authentication used by ms office in my app?

Tags: authentication, sharepoint, ms-office

When you start MS Office application (Word 2013 or Excel 2013) you can use "Sign In" to login to your account, and afterwards Office uses that login/password to connect to your stuff online (like your sharepoint site or your onedrive).

These credentials are stored in VAULT (user credentials), you have something like `MicrosoftOffice15_Data:orgid:bla-bla-bla`. Is it possible to re-use these saved credentials to connect to user's stuff, so that he does not need to enter these second time?

I.e. is it possible to connect to user's stuff using these credentials from my app by somehow using those credentials office asked user to enter?

Answer (score 0):

If your app is an "App for Office" app, I guess you automagically use the current credentials. You might also be able to use vba to do stuff with these credentials.

If your app is completely separate, I guess there is no chance.

Comment: My App is an add-in (in-process, VSTO, not "App for Office"), but it does seem not seem to have these credentials "automatically" for some reason. I.e. if I want to access some resource office has access to, not specifying any credentials for example, I get access denied.